# Loaded model has incorrect number of features

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pickle

I am using sci-kitlearn and pickle (in order to save my trained model).

First off, the following code is executed:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

logreg = LogisticRegression(solver='lbfgs', multi_class='auto')
logreg.fit(X_train, y_train)

with open('text_classifier', 'wb') as picklefile:
    pickle.dump(logreg, picklefile)
```

When I want to use this model again later I use (to check it still works):

```
with open('text_classifier', 'rb') as training_model:
    model = pickle.load(training_model)

print('Accuracy of Logistic regression classifier on test set: {:.2f}\n'
      .format(model.score(X_test, y_test)))
```

However, this throws the following error:

`ValueError: X has 74 features per sample; expecting 77`

Could someone explain to me why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the columns in your train and test are identical? Apparently your X_test set has 74 columns while the model is expecting to have 77 columns.
Have you sampled the data before training? It could be because of improper sampling.

If your dataset is intact then this should work just fine:

```
pickle.dump(logreg, open('text_classifier.sav', 'wb'))
model = pickle.load(open('text_classifier.sav', 'rb'))
```

This might help: Scikit-learn documentation on model persistence (pickle and joblib):
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html

Comment: Just running those 2 lines makes it work ok, it's just not working when having them in separate executions

Comment: In the link I posted (sklearn docs), the only mention of using the model in a separate python process is when the page suggests using `joblib` and not `pickle`. Try using joblib. Save model with `from joblib import dump, load` then `dump(logreg, 'text_classifier.joblib')` and then load with `model = load('text_classifier.joblib')`

Comment: I still had the same issue